# Python 2.7: efficiently reformat list of tuples

Tags: python, string, list

I would like to reformat the following list containing tuples with integers (shared between some tuples) and strings (idiosyncratic to each tuple)

```
mylist = [(8, 'dddd'), (8, '33333'), (8, 'fdsss'), (9, 'fsfjs'),(10, 'dddd'), (10, '33333'), (12, 'fdsss'), (12, 'fsfjs')]
```

so that each tuple contains an integer and a concatenated string of all strings belonging to it, like so:

```
mynewlist = [(8, 'dddd, 33333, fdsss'), (9, 'fsfjs'),(10, 'dddd, 333333'), (12, 'fdsss, fsfjs')
```

After some deliberation, the most parsimonious solution I've come up with is to simply loop across all tuples and concatenate strings until the integer doesn't match the next one:

```
mynewlist = []
label = ''
for i in range(len(mylist)-1):
    if mylist[i][0] != mylist[i+1][0]:
        mynewlist.append(tuple([mylist[i][0], label + mylist[i][1]]))
        label = ''
    else:
        label = label + mylist[i][1] + ','
```

This works fine. However, I'd like to know if there's a more efficient/Pythonic way of producing the list. I considered using a list comprehension, but this wouldn't allow me to select the strings without going through the whole list many times over; the list comprehension would need to be run for each unique integer, which seems wasteful. I also considered pre-selecting the strings associated with a unique integer through indexing, but this appears quite un-Pythonic to me.

Advice is very appreciated. Thanks!

Answer (score 6):

You could use [`itertools.groupby()`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/itertools.html#itertools.groupby) to do the grouping here:

```
from itertools import groupby
from operator import itemgetter

mynewlist = [
    (key, ', '.join([s for num, s in group]))
    for key, group in groupby(mylist, itemgetter(0))]
```

This uses [list comprehensions](https://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/datastructures.html#list-comprehensions) to process each group and extract the strings from the grouped tuples for concatenation. The [`operator.itemgetter()` object](https://docs.python.org/2/library/operator.html#operator.itemgetter) tells `groupby()` to group the input on the first element:

```
>>> from itertools import groupby
>>> from operator import itemgetter
>>> mylist = [(8, 'dddd'), (8, '33333'), (8, 'fdsss'), (9, 'fsfjs'),(10, 'dddd'), (10, '33333'), (12, 'fdsss'), (12, 'fsfjs')]
>>> [(key, ', '.join([s for num, s in group])) for key, group in groupby(mylist, itemgetter(0))]
[(8, 'dddd, 33333, fdsss'), (9, 'fsfjs'), (10, 'dddd, 33333'), (12, 'fdsss, fsfjs')]
```

Note that the `groupby()` iterator groups only *consecutive* matching elements. That means if your input is not sorted, then tuples with the same initial element are not necessarily going to always be put together either. If your input is not sorted and you need all tuples with the same starting element to be grouped regardless of where they are in the input sequence, use a dictionary to group the elements first:

```
grouped = {}
for key, string in mylist:
    grouped.setdefault(key, []).append(string)
mynewlist = [(key, ', '.join([s for num, s in group])) for key, group in grouped.items()]
```

Answer (score 2):

A `defaultdict` would do the trick:

```
from collections import defaultdict
dct = defaultdict(list)
for k, v in mylist:
    dct[k].append(v)
mynewlist = [(k, ','.join(v)) for k, v in dct.iteritems()]
```

Answer (score -1):

You can do it with a custom `dict` subclass:

```
class mydict(dict):
    def __setitem__(self, key, val):
        self.setdefault(key,[]).append(val)

>>> mylist = [(8, 'dddd'), (8, '33333'), (8, 'fdsss'),
...           (9, 'fsfjs'),(10, 'dddd'), (10, '33333'),
...           (12, 'fdsss'), (12, 'fsfjs')]
>>> d = mydict()
>>> for key, val in mylist:
...     d[key] = val
```

Now `d` contains something like

```
{8: ['dddd', '33333', 'fdsss'], 9: ['fsfjs'], 10: ['dddd', '33333'], 12: ['fdsss', 'fsfjs']}
```

(to within order of items), and you can easily massage this into the form you want:

```
result = [(key,', '.join(d[key])) for key, value in d]
```

Comment: A new subclass is... Overkill. Use a `defaultdict` or `dict.setdefault()` approach instead. But if you do, implement a `__missing__` instead of overriding `__setitem__`.

Comment: Also, the OP wanted the strings *concatenated*, not as a nested tuple.

Comment: @MartijnPieters `(key,) + tuple(d[key])` gives a flat tuple.

Comment: Right, but it is not two elements (number and concatenated string).

Comment: @MartijnPieters Ah, and oops: yes, `(8, 'dddd, 33333, fdsss')`. Thus `(key,', '.join(d[key]))` — fixed.